# How can I disable greeting message when ssh in to a server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Every time - I `ssh` into my server I keep getting

ssh root@12.34.56.78

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Thu Jul  2 10:58:35 EDT 2015

  System load:  0.16               Processes:           90
  Usage of /:   13.5% of 19.56GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 25%                IP address for eth0: 12.34.56.78
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for eth1: 10.10.10.10

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

Last login: Thu Jul  2 10:58:35 2015 from 50-198-81-174-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
```

It's okay to showing at my first time logging into the server.
But seeing this message all the time - I find that a little unnecessary.

Can someone please show me how to disable it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most sane solution, if it's your own server, would be to disable the motd in in the SSH daemon config. Set `PrintMotd` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `no` and restart the ssh daemon.

Alternatively, you can try to `touch ~/.hushlogin`, which creates an empty file in your home folder. Daemons that allow remote logins traditionally check for presence of this file and if it is present, they will let you log in quietly.

Comment: hmm... I guess I will do that then. Thank-you !  Which one of these 2 that you suggest one over another ? and why ?

Comment: Also, I just checked, my `PrintMotd` is already set to `no`. Trying your last suggestion now.

Comment: this works, there's no /etc/update-motd.d on my Debian servers

Answer (score 2):

Or, if the motd is set to `no`, and you don't want to use .hushlogin, you can edit `/etc/motd` or `/etc/update-motd.d/*` and just wipe it's contents, so you will still be notified by the "last login" message.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the file `/etc/pam.d/sshd` - comment those 2 lines:

Before:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

After:

```
#session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
#session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```