# Disable ssh message

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I connect to Ubuntu-based Docker container via SSH, following message will be shown every time.

```
The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.
```

I want to disable showing it, but I couldn't find how.
Is there any way to do it? If it's possible, please let me know how.

Comment: Just read this : https://askubuntu.com/a/100058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer for now:

```
 sed -i 's/PrintLastLog yes/PrintLastLog no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
 touch /home/$USER/.hushlogin
```

I need PrintLastLog no and .hashlogin at home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can make them disappear using the following commands.
You can simply forward that message to a file and then delete it while you log out.

```
ssh -t user@192.168.XXX.XXX '> dis.txt; bash -l'
```

Note -t option is necessary to execute bash commands.

However this will ask for password. A more simplified version of the above and pure thing is to use sshpass.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -t user@192.168.XXX.XXX '> dis.txt; bash -l'
```

The above one is plain simple it will just connect simply.

Remember to replace 'password' and 'user' and host address.

Before log out just insert the following command

```
rm dis.txt
```

The last step is not needed actually it is up to you to decide.

Refer this :[How can I disable greeting message when ssh in to a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188489/how-can-i-disable-greeting-message-when-ssh-in-to-a-server)